# Is it possible to choose $10$ distinct numbers from the set $\{0, 1, 2, . . . , 14\}$ so that various differences are all distinct?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, contest-math

From the 1991 Canada National Olympiad:

> Can ten distinct numbers $a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2, b_3, c_1, c_2, d_1, d_2, d_3$ be chosen from $\{0, 1, 2, \dotsc, 14\}$ so that the $14$ differences $$
>   \begin{matrix}
>     |a_1 − b_1| & |a_1 − b_2| & |a_1 − b_3| \\
>     |a_2 − b_1| & |a_2 − b_2| & |a_2 − b_3| \\ 
>     |c_1 − d_1| & |c_1 − d_2| & |c_1 − d_3| \\ 
>     |c_2 − d_1| & |c_2 − d_2| & |c_2 − d_3| \\
>   \end{matrix}
>   \\
>   \begin{matrix}
>     |a_1 − c_1| & |a_2 − c_2|
>   \end{matrix}
> $$
>   are all distinct?

My observations so far:

- There are $14$ differences, none of which can be zero. So the differences must comprise the set $\{1, 2, \dotsc , 14\}$.
- The ten numbers must include both of $\{0, 14\}$ and at least one of $\{1, 13\}$.
- Subsets $A, C$ are the most central, as they also have differences with each other. If trying to construct a positive example for the choice of ten numbers, an unwise choice of $a_1, a_2$ or $c_1, c_2$ may quickly restrict other choices. Subsets $B, D$ are less central and could perhaps accomodate more awkward choices.

The diagram indicates which pairwise set differences are included in the $14$. Note that the dotted line from $A$ to $C$ indicates that not all combinations of pairwise differences are taken.

[image: Pairwise differences]

Some of the work of Solomon Golomb, e.g. a [Golomb Ruler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb_ruler), may be of tangential interest, although the solution to this problem **must** be simpler than that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Concept tested:** [Parity](https://brilliant.org/wiki/parity-medium/)

Observe that each term appears an even number of times in all of the absolute values.

Can the sum of absolute values be $1+2+3+\ldots + 14 = 105$?

Comment: ... and very quick!

Comment: That's a neat trick!